# Make a picture different than the other pages in CSS

Tags: css

1. Hi , i'm a beginner and I tried some ideas from this website or on
   google but I can't make it work.  I have differents pages and in the
   "about" page I would like to change the border around my picture but
   i can't find out how to , because in my css there is a border for
   all pictures. So my question is what to write in css so that i'll be
   able to modify every single element of each page ? I tried "id" but
   it doesn't change anything :/ thank you :)

Comment: This is not even a question. Please read the very basics of CSS: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_intro.asp  -  you use classes or ids to select specific elements. You will learn very slowly if you ask SO question on something this basic

Comment: Can you post some example code (HTML /CSS)? Have you tried adding `id="myid"` attribute to your special image, and create a style using `#myid { }`

Comment: Hello welcome to SO, have you seen the big yellow box before posting a question, with information about [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a good question?

Comment: yes , I thought it was clear actually. I tried to post my css but it was saying there was mistakes in it. So I tried to make a clear question ahah

Answer (score 0):

Best practice would be to add a class to the image you want to style differently like this

```
<img class="about-page-image" src="...">
```

and then define the css like this

```
img {
    border: 3px solid green; // applies to all images
}
img.about-page-image {
    border-color: red; // overrides rule above
}
```

Comment: Glad to hear that, but as @Milney already suggested you should read some basic tutorials about css to get a better understanding ;)